# Responsive / equal div height

Tags: html, css, layout

I have been trying all night to get some divs to be equal height.

Here is my JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4cj5LbLs/15/

I have tried using `display: table;` in the parent with `display: table-cell;` or `display: table-column;` in the child, as you can see in the fiddle but it just doesn't make the divs equal height.

I did see a way using flex but they say it's incompatible with IE9 and lower and I'd like to be as compatible as possible.

How can I get these CSS tables working here or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

*Edit: I'd also like to note that I only want the columns in a row to be equal height but only when they are side by side. When the screen is < 800px the columns get stacked and then they are the content height.

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS solution only?

Comment: I guess, I just want to know what is the best and most compatible way to achieve my goal. Are you going to suggest HTML tables? Is that the best way?

Comment: You should not believe everything *they* tell you. Open my solution in IE9. As for "lower"... Well, Microsoft has officially discontinued support for IE8. If they no longer support it, who do you think is still using it?

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu IE 8.0, 0.6% of my users it says on my report. I shall try flexbox though and see how I get on.

Comment: 0.6% of your users is you, trying to see if it works on IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flex box for this. i change in your html and it look like this

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="full-width-container">
        <div class="full-width-wrapper">
            <div class="full-width">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="three-columns-container three-columns-first">
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="three-columns">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three-columns-container three-columns-second">
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="three-columns">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three-columns-container three-columns-third">
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="three-columns">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="full-width-container">
        <div class="full-width-wrapper">
            <div class="full-width">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="two-columns-container two-columns-first">
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="two-columns">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-columns-container two-columns-second">
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="two-columns">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="sixty-container">
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="sixty-forty">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="forty-container">
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="sixty-forty">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Columns */

.row {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row div {
  /* min-height: 200px; */
}
.three-columns {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Full width column */

.full-width-container {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width-wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px;
}

.full-width {
  background-color: rgb(225, 221, 213);
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
}

/* Three columns */

.three-columns-container {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
  width:30.6666%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.three-columns-first, .three-columns-second {;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.three-columns-third {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.three-columns {
  background-color: rgb(225, 221, 213);
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
}

/* Two columns */

.two-columns-container {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.two-columns-first {;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.two-columns {
  background-color: rgb(225, 221, 213);
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
}

.column-wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.two-columns-container p, .full-width-container p, .two-columns-container p, .column-wrapper p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* Two columns (60/40) */

.sixty-container {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 57.6%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.forty-container {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 38.4%;
}

.sixty-forty {
  background-color: rgb(225, 221, 213);
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
}

.three-columns-second, .three-columns-third {;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .three-columns-first { 
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .three-columns-second { 
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .three-columns-third {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sixty-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .forty-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .two-columns-first { 
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .two-columns-second { 
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* END Columns */
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to restructure your display-table. You cannot use margins or floats with display-tables as that would defeat the purpose of a table.

Also, I left the @media stuff out because I don't have time to work that in and for that I apologize. I do hope this can get you started though.

**NOTE**: If a table-cell is empty, using the code I provided, it will throw it all off. It will however accept `&nbsp;` to correct it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 50px;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}
.cell-wrapper {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  width: 33%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell-padding {
  height: 100%;
}
.cell-content {
  background-color: rgb(225, 221, 213);
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell-wrapper">
      <div class="cell-padding">
        <div class="cell-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-wrapper">
      <div class="cell-padding">
        <div class="cell-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-wrapper">
      <div class="cell-padding">
        <div class="cell-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell-wrapper">
      <div class="cell-padding">
        <div class="cell-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-wrapper">
      <div class="cell-padding">
        <div class="cell-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-wrapper">
      <div class="cell-padding">
        <div class="cell-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using flex. You have to wrap the `table-cell` with a container set to `display:table-row;`.

If you don't specify the `width` for `table-cell` then they can be of unequal `width` to minimize the height, but if you don't want that you can simply add `width` to them.

See this example:

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:table;
}
.row{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:table-row;
}
.inside{
  display:table-cell;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="inside one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inside two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inside three">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```